# Obtener Id de una fila de dataTable

Tags: php, javascript, datatables, datatable

Estoy trabajando una dataTable en un archivo php.
En la última columna puse un par de botones (eliminar/editar).
Mi duda ahora es ¿Cómo obtener el Id al momento de hacer click en ellos? para poder mandar las instrucciones SQL y eliminar o actualizar los datos de esa fila en especifico.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var tabla_In =$('#dataTableIn').DataTable({
"ajax":{
  "url": "mantenedor_web/indice_web_JSON.php",
  "dataSrc": ""
},
"columns":[
  {"data": "Id_doc_indice"},
  {"data": "num_doc_indice"},
  {"data": "tit_doc_indice"},
  {"data": "null",
    "className": "center",
    "defaultContent": '<button class="tableBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong"><i class="fas fa-file-alt fa-lg"></i></button>'
  },
  {"data": "desc_doc_info"},
  {"data": "null",
    "className": "center",
    "defaultContent": '<button type="button" class="tableBtn editar" value="btnMod" id="btnMod" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalMod" ><i class="fas fa-pen fa-lg"></i></button>/<button class="table_del_Btn" id="btnDel" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalDel"><i class="fas fa-trash fa-lg"></i></button>'
  }
]
});
});
</script>
<!--Fin Tbody tabla-->
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código que tienes para capturar el clic en los botones.

Comment: La documentación de DateTable tiene una sección sobre [events](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/dt_events.html), ahí puedes comprobar cómo funciona. Si añades el código completo de tu tabla, podemos ayudarte con una respuesta más específica. Espero que te sirva.